# How to place the image for every cell in tableview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

iam developing one application.In that i place the imageview in every tableview cell like

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

          static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
          UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    itemimageview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 8, 75, 70)];
    itemimageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb_mdpi.png"];
    itemimageview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:itemimageview];
    return cell;
}
```

And when u click any row we get the image from our iPhone camera.For that i write the below code in didSelectROw method.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]
                                                                  autorelease];
imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
//imagePicker.allowsImageEditing = NO;
imagePicker.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

After i use the UIIMagePickerController delegate method like

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSLog(@"image selected");
    itemimageview.image =image;
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But my problem is after selecting the image,that image will be appear at last cell only.If u select first row and take the image then that image will be appear at last row.So please tell me what are the changes in my code for getting the image for every row.

Comment: you check simple by adding a breakpoints on code. Or you use switch case and write code as when click on row one then this image display and when second row select then show this image.I think u get any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by following these steps:
1.First when the user clicks a cell, store the row number (indexPath.row) in an integer variable.
2.Once you have acquired the image from the camera,store it in a UIImage.
3.Now you know the row to be updated and you have ur image.Call reloadData method of the UITableView at the end of the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo delegate method.
4.The reloadData method will subsequently call the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. In that have a condition like this:

```
if(indexPath.row==clickedRow){
  //Create the imageView here and then assign the image obtained from the camera to it.
  imageView.image=cameraImage;
  [cell.contentView addSubView:imageView];
```

}
where clickedRow is the integer variable which holds the row number clicked by the user in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used ur code.But at the time of assign the image to the selected row i got the error like Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.How to solve this one

Comment: Check whether you release the imageview object twice.Releasing an object twice could result it such kind of crash.

Comment: @Naresh Or u might be releasing an object which u didnt allocate.

Comment: I allocated the memory for imageview and released that one

Comment: Could u please post ur code ? It would be more easy to spot where the mistake lies.

Comment: Ok below one is the CellForRowIndex method codeUITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
  itemimageview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 8, 75, 70)];
 if(indexPath.row==selectedRow)
 {
  itemimageview.image=rowImage;
 }
 else 
 {
  itemimageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb_mdpi.png"];
 }

  
  itemimageview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Comment: [cell.contentView addSubview:itemimageview];
 return cell;
}

Comment: error will be occur at itemimageview.image=rowImage;rowImage is the uiimage object.

Comment: I got that one.Simply i convert that image data to NSdata.And used that NSdata.Thank U

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting itemimageview to the image view  inside the most recent cell the tableview grabbed from the delegate method each time a cell is drawn so itemimageview will contain the last image that the tableview drew.

In order to fix it you will have to make sure to update the imageview of the cell that was actually clicked.  I think the easiest way to do this would be to use use Apple's default cell imageview with `cell.image`. Or you could make a subclass of UITableViewCell that keeps track of and draws the UIImageView.  Then you change the image in that cell that is selected.

Either way you will need to keep track of which cell was selected in that class.  One way could be to put `UITableViewCell selectedCell;` in the .h. then `selectedCell = [self cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` in your didSelect method followed by `selectedCell.image = image` in your image delegate.

Sorry if this is hard to follow, it's a short answer to a moderately complex problem.  There are many ways to tackle this.